# PowerShell Functions and not repeating code

Tags: powershell

these last couple of days I've been breaking my head on functions and parameters. I would really like to be able to enhance my function to delete files by having it run on the remote server with the `Invoke-Command` but without repeating the code.

What I would like to be able to do within my script is to call the function like this:

- `Delete-OldFiles "\\Domain\Share\Dir1" "10" "Auto_Clean.log"`
- `Delete-OldFiles "SERVER1" "C:\Share\Dir1" "10" "Auto_Clean.log"`

The first call of the function works perfectly and executes the function on the local server. With the second call I want to pass the server name to the function so it will execute the script on the remote server.

I'm sure there must be an option to enable this `Invoke-Command`within the function when the server name is provided and without having to write the code twice... But I just can't seem to get my head around it.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Server -ScriptBlock ${Function:Delete-OldFiles} -ArgumentList ($_.Server,$_.Path,$_.OlderThanDays,"Auto_Clean.log")`

**My function**

```
Function Delete-OldFiles {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)] # Add -WhatIf support for dry run
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
    [String]$Server,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [String]$Target,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
    [Int]$OlderThanDays,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
    [String]$LogName
      )

if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge "3") {

# PowerShell 3+ Remove files older than (FASTER)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Exclude $LogName -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | ForEach {
        $Item = $_.FullName
        Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
        # If files can't be removed
        if (Test-Path $Item)
            { "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)" } 
        else
            { "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item" }  
        } | Tee-Object $Target\$LogName -Append } # Output file names to console & logfile at the same time

Else {               

# PowerShell 2 Remove files older than
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Exclude $LogName -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | ForEach {
        $Item = $_.FullName
        Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
        # If files can't be removed
        if (Test-Path $Item)
            { 
            Write-Host "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
            "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Server $Item (IN USE)"
             } 
        else
            { 
            Write-Host "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item"
            "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Server $Item"
            }  
        } |  Out-File $Target\$LogName -Append } 
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems to be something usefull, but I don't know if it's best practice.. http://learningpcs.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/powershell-nested-functions.html

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I want to pass the server name to the function so it will execute the script on the remote server". If you're using **Invoke-Command** to execute the function remotely (your code for that is correct), why would you need to pass the server name as an argument to the function itself? Or do you mean that you want to add a **-ComputerName** parameter to the function *instead* of executing it with **Invoke-Command**, and have the function itself handle the remote execution? Or is your **Invoke-Command** code not producing the expected results? (If so, in which way?)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Adi. The ˋInvoke-Commandˋ line i wrote is indeed correct and works just fine. But I would rather pass the ˋ-ComputerNameˋ to the Function as a parameter, so that when I use it the function will be executed remote and otherwise on the local server. So yes, I would like to have the function itself to decide when to execute it remotely, when the server name is given